# Excel VBA: runtime error 13 - type mismatch while collapsing the pivotitems

Tags: vba, runtime-error, pivot-table, pivotitem

I am trying to collapse the pivot items through loop using VBA. Below is the code:

```
Dim oPI As PivotItems

For Each oPI In ActiveSheet.PivotTables("PivotTable4").PivotFields("TAG").PivotItems
oPI.ShowDetail = False
Next oPI
```

I am getting Runtime error 13 - "Type mismatch" error. Not sure what is wrong with this code.
Could anyone please let me know what changes to make?

Comment: This is sorted now. By mistake I had declared as PivotItems instead PivotItem.

Answer (score 0):

Replace your declaration for `oPi`:

```
Dim oPi as Object
```

will achieve what you want. A `For Each` loop requires a variable of type Object/Variant.

Answer (score 0):

Use this mate:

```
ActiveSheet.PivotTables("Name_of_your_pitot_table").PivotFields("pivot_field_name").ShowDetail = False
```